# bash - True if the length of string is (non)zero?

Tags: shell-script, variable, string, test

```
# touch $$
# gzip $$
# gzip --test $$.gz
# echo $?
0
# OUT=$(gzip --test $$.gz)
# echo $OUT

# if [ -z $OUT ] ; then echo $$ ; fi
26521
# if [ -n $OUT ] ; then echo $$ ; fi
26521
#
```

---

from `bash(1)`

> ```
>    -z string
>           True if the length of string is zero.
>    string
>    -n string
>           True if the length of string is non-zero.
> ```

I'm confused, how is it zero *and* non-zero at the same time? How does one do check against if key has a value (using `bash`)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`[ .. ]` follows the same rules as all other commands, namely [Word Splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) applies. If `OUT` is empty (or unset), `$OUT` will expand to nothing, not even an empty argument.

So, `[ -n $OUT ]` expands to `[`, `-n` and `]`, and `[` tests if `-n` is not an empty string. It is, so the test returns true.

You need to quote `$OUT`, as almost everywhere else:

```
if [ -n "$OUT" ]; then ...
```

See: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)
and [Tests and Conditionals](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29) on BashGuide.

Answer (score 5):

The command

```
[ -z $OUT ]
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
test -z $OUT
```

which, if `$OUT` is empty, is the same as

```
test -z
```

The behaviour of `test` [depends on the number of parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/test.html) given on the command line.  If given only a single parameter, as in `test -n` or `test -z`, the result will be "true" if the length of that parameter, when interpreted as a string, is non-zero.

This means that if `$OUT` is empty and unquoted, then `test -z $OUT` and `test -n $OUT` will both be true because `-z` and `-n` are both strings of non-zero length.

To remedy this, double-quote the variable expansion:

```
[ -n "$OUT" ]
```

See also

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)